# Convert string to javascript date object

Tags: javascript, ajax, string, utc

Im trying to convert UTC date to the current date for the x axis on a chart.  I'm pretty sure I'm not using `Date.parse` correctly.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/chart/ajax_get_chart", // the URL of the controller action method
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        var result = JSON.parse(result);
        series = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          date = Date.parse(result[i]['date']); 
          tempArray = [parseFloat(result[i]['price'])];
          series.push(tempArray);
          series.push(date);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change the value of the function `Date.parse`; you wrote:

```
Date.parse = result[i]['date'];
```

You need to *call* this function to parse the date

Try

```
Date.parse(result[i]['date'])
```

and assign the result of this call to some variable to hold the date.

[Date.parse documentation from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not sure on what to do after I assign the result

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't know what you _want_ to do with it.  I see that you are pushing prices to an array; is the array supposed to contain both dates and prices?

Comment: I want two separate arrays, the problem is that the date and time on the x-axis of the chart is not correct.  Im correctly getting the arrays in my console.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

> The [`Date.parse`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.4.2) method is completely *implementation dependent*
>   (`new Date(string)` is equivalent to [`Date.parse(string)`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.4.2)).
>
> I would recommend you to parse your date string manually, and use the
>   [Date constructor](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.3.1) with the year, month and day arguments to avoid
>   ambiguity:
>
> ```
> // parse a date in yyyy-mm-dd format
> function parseDate(input) {
>   var parts = input.split('-');
>   // new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
>   return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // months are 0-based
> }
> ```